# How should I manage the memory allocated for the UIView returned from viewForHeaderInSection?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm about to implement the UITableViewDelegate::viewForHeaderInSection method, where I plan to allocate and init a new UIView object and return it.  I'm new to iOS development, but I'm trying to adhere to the general rule of thumb that if I create it, I'm responsible for deleting it, but I can figure out how the UIView object is handled after I pass it on to the UITableView.  Should I autorelease the UIView object?  Should I store it in an instance var and release it in my dealloc?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would autorelease the UIView.

I would only store it in an instance variable if you need an reference to it later.

Comment: Yes but what if you don't use ARC? And what if the answer was given a year before ARC was introduced?